# Where to download all polymer elements as zip file?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.0 is released recently and I can download the elements à la carte at the [elements.polymer-project.org](https://elements.polymer-project.org/) site, but I can't find an easy link to download everything in one big zip file?

Any idea where they are hiding it?

Comment: Checkout [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit/releases) for beginners that includes **almost** all the elements.

And download the missing elements as a ZIP file as suggested [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/using-elements#installing-from-zip-files).

Missing elements:

- Google Web Components
- Gold Elements

Answer (score 13):

If you are using bower run these commands:

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/iron-elements  
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-elements  
bower install --save PolymerElements/gold-elements  
bower install --save PolymerElements/neon-elements  
bower install --save PolymerElements/platinum-elements  
bower install --save GoogleWebComponents/google-web-components
bower install --save PolymerElements/app-elements
```

Comment: also works for app elements: bower install --save PolymerElements/app-elements

Comment: How to do the same for polymer 2? This works for polymer 1.

Answer (score 6):

You can download a set of components as a ZIP file as suggested [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/using-elements#installing-from-a-zip-file).

Follow these steps to download all of the current catalog elements as a single ZIP file:

1. Browse to https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse
2. Click the ☆ next to each element you wish to download.

   - The ☆ will be filled (★) when selected.
   - All of the elements dependencies will be included in the ZIP file.
   - You can select all the elements if desired.
3. Click on the [image: star icon] at the top of the page.
4. Select the **Download** tab.
5. Select the **elements folder** radio button.
6. Click the **Download** button.

[image: steps]

Note:  Keep in mind that if you choose this method (ZIP file) you will have to manage dependency updates on your own.  It is recommended that you use bower instead.

Comment: Great job, thanks. Does license allow posting the result zip? maybe we can post a link to it here

Comment: You can take a look at the *LICENSE.txt* in the *polymer* folder of the download.  It does look like redistribution is ok.  I would suggest looking for any licenses with the individual elements as well.  That said, I would really not recommend doing this.  Almost as soon as the ZIP file was posted it would be out of date.  As mentioned in my answer *bower* is the recommended way to grab these elements.  Using bower has a lot of advantages over ZIP files.

Comment: Seems like if if you select too many, the download tab disappears. I removed all but a few and it became visible again.

Comment: @JoeLove A lot has changed in two years and this was never the recommended way of using polymer.

Comment: @coderfin I believe that, it's just annoying that to even try polymer elements you have to download about ~6 gig of stuff on a mac to serve up a few K of javascript files. All I wanted was a "sandbox" to see if polymer is even something we want to pursue.

Comment: Dead link. https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse returns 404 (not found). Should use Bower or Yarn as the dependency manager.