# How to install / download complete package of Polymer elements?

Tags: bower, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am trying to develope polymer web pages.We have to refer polymer elements from bower_components under project to use them. but i dont have files available over there.Is there any library available which has all components(eg. paper/iron etc) html files so that I can refer them into my project.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to install a component is to use bower.  Bower manages dependencies for you and handles updating.

[You can read about installing components from bower, ZIP, and GitHub here.](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/getting-the-code.html)

If you want a single ZIP with all the currently available components you can read my answer to [Where to download all polymer elements as zip file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552251/where-to-download-all-polymer-elements-as-zip-file/31390602#31390602).

There is also a project at http://element-party.xyz/ that can be used to reference the latest versions of components.

> You can import all the latest polymer elements easily into your jsbin (or otherwise) by simply doing:

```
<base href="http://element-party.xyz/" />
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="all-elements.html" />
```

Components can be reference collectively, as shown above, or individually. Click on the *Usage* tab at http://element-party.xyz/ to learn more. http://element-party.xyz/ frequently updates to the *bleeding edge*, because of this I would not recommend using it in production.

You can also take a look at http://polygit.org/.

> The *Magic Server* serves files directly from github (via
>   `cdn.rawgit.com`) in a manner that is compatible with HTML Imports
>   natural deduplication feature.
>
> This server concept is primarily for hit-and-run testing, jsbins, etc. The performance is less than ideal and there is very little error reporting or other niceties.

http://polygit.org/ does have an interesting ability to specify **Custom Configuration** that allows for specifying specific versions of files. `<component>[+<org>]+<ver>|:<branch>|*`

Comment: Thanks a lot @codefin ... I will follow your instruction.

Answer (score 0):

[GoTo](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) and click the download button or grab their project from github and all their source are belong to you ;)